# Valid CSS with new properties

Tags: css, webkit, w3c-validation

I am using a few CSS tricks to boost up the usability/appearance of my site in Webkit browsers. The two main ones are `text-shadow` and `resize:none` (on textareas - to stop that annoying page-breaking resize option in Safari and others).

The problem is that when I run my page through the W3 validator I get tons of:

> Property text-shadow doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in : #feb4b4 1px 1px 0 #feb4b4 1px 1px 0

-and-

> Property resize doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in : none none

Is this really not valid? Should I really not use this, or is it an error to just ignore?

Comment: Questions asking about code that is not working or validating need to include the code you have used. This also includes information about what level of validation you are trying to run; we can _infer_ that you are running it against CSS 2.1 but don't know if you intended to check against that or if you intended to check against CSS 3. Thus this question should be closed in its current state as it needs more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text-shadow` property is a CSS3 property. If you pick CSS Level 3 from the advanced options on the W3 CSS Validtor service, it should come through okay. It was also in CSS Level 2, but dropped for CSS Level 2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Both text-shadow and resize are only valid properties in CSS 3, they were only implemented in previous versions of CSS by the browsers but were never officially supported. If you want to use them, you really should use CSS 3 instead.

Comment: do you mean to use CSS3 as the option in the validator? or to actually switch my CSS to CSS3? if so, how do i switch the actual CSS?

Comment: If the browser supports it, CSS 3 properties will automatically be used without having to do anything. You'd have to tell W3C to use CSS3 when evaluating your stylesheets though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the proprietary browser equivs of the prpoerties in question like `-webkit-text-shadow` and `-webkit-resize` i **think** that will allow the css to validate while still letting you use the properties (even on level 2).

The down side is you have to mimic this for Mozilla as well like `-moz-text-shadow` if you want to use it there... and assuming IE eventually starts to support these then you might go back and clean it up replacing them all with the single property declaration in the spec.

Comment: All of those still report invalid properties in the W3C validator, because they are invalid.

Comment: @animuson: +1 i was just about to update to that effect. Iw as under the mistaken impression that the validator (like browsers) would just ignore them.