# How can I validate my CSS3 document?

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I use the jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ CSS validator, but since upgrading to CSS3, I get error "border-radius doesn't exist in CSS v2.1". How can I make it check via CSS3 so that it doesn't leave any errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid CSS with new properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187244/valid-css-with-new-properties)

Comment: @Madmartigan: Trying to find a better duplicate but having so much trouble. If all else fails, let's edit that one to death :)

Comment: @BoltClock: I actually found a lot, but they were all a bit too specific in some regard, not unlike this one. SO really needs a true FAQ/wiki system. Anyways, here's a couple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786957/validator-gives-error-on-css3-properties, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931040/css-validation-not-validating I actually think this one is the best one, close the others ;)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Select CSS Level 3]

Answer (score 0):

Click More Options, then select `CSS Level 3`.

Answer (score 0):

for Valid CSS 3 by using the same link you would normally use and just add the key-value pair “profile=css3″ to the query string like this:

```
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://yoururl.com&profile=css3
```

Or by referer

```
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer?profile=css3
```